# Solve $y''+y=\cos^2(x)$ by variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

The answer I got is 
$$y=c_1 \cos(x) + c_2 \sin(x) + \frac{1}{2} \sin(2x) + \frac{1}{3} \cos(2x).$$
Can the last two trig terms be simplified further?

Comment: Only if you want to write $\;\frac12\sin2x=\sin x\cos x\;$ and $\;\frac13\cos2x=\frac13(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)\;$ or something equivalent. I think it already looks just fine.

Comment: I would leave it the way it is...you could say something like $C\cos (x-\phi) + \sqrt {\frac {13}{36}}\cos (2x-\arctan{\frac 32})$ but I don't think that is simpler.

Comment: I believe you're missing a constant in your particular solution, since $$\cos^2 x = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\cos 2x$$

Comment: Also, is there a reason you would want to simplify this expression further? It's already simple enough

Comment: @Jenny Lian : Before trying to simplify, check your result : $y=c_1 \cos(x) + c_2 \sin(x) + \frac{1}{2} \sin(2x) + \frac{1}{3} \cos(2x)$ which is false.

Answer (score 1):

$$y''+y=\cos^2(x) \tag 1$$
Your answer 
$\quad y=c_1 \cos(x) + c_2 \sin(x) + \frac{1}{2} \sin(2x) + \frac{1}{3} \cos(2x)\quad$ is FALSE.

Why didn't you put it back into Eq.$(1)$ in order to check your result ?

You should find :
$$y=c_1 \cos(x) + c_2 \sin(x) - \frac{1}{6} \cos(2x)+\frac12$$

$y'=-c_1 \sin(x) + c_2 \cos(x) + \frac{1}{3} \sin(2x)$

$y''=-c_1 \cos(x) - c_2 \sin(x) + \frac{2}{3} \cos(2x)$

$y''+y=\frac{2}{3} \cos(2x)- \frac{1}{6} \cos(2x)+\frac12 = \frac{\cos(2x)+1}{2}=\cos^2(x)$